# C#. HttpWebRequest connect ForwardedPort ssh.net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I tried the software like Proxifier, ProxyCap ... to run parallel with my software, but it's quite inconvenient.

You take a look at my code below and tell me what I need to be able to do so or. Please show me a certain way can do that. thanks.

Problem: can not get response to the website whoer.net via ip ssh been

i have code

```
ForwardedPort port = new ForwardedPortDynamic("127.0.0.1", 5011); // proxy
            SshClient client = new SshClient("192.32.2.1", "admin", "admin"); //ssh
            client.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
            client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
            try
            {
                client.ErrorOccurred += delegate (object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.ExceptionEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client error: " + e.Exception.Message);
                };
                client.HostKeyReceived += delegate (object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.HostKeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");
                    Console.WriteLine("Key Exchanged");
                };

                port.RequestReceived += delegate (object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.PortForwardEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Requested connection to " + e.OriginatorHost + ":" + e.OriginatorPort);
                };

                client.Connect();

                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    client.SendKeepAlive();
                    client.AddForwardedPort(port);
                    port.Start();


                    HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://whoer.net");
                    rq.Method = "GET";
                    rq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    using (HttpWebResponse rp = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse())
                    {
                        string result = new StreamReader(rp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(result); 
                    };


                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client did not connect");

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

Comment: what is a concrete problem ?

Comment: can not get response to the website whoer.net via ip ssh been